# What does "ガッツンガッツン" mean?

Tags: translation, onomatopoeia

From here: http://doge-sucha.com/2018/12/zaregoto-1328/

I've seen this before on slangy dialogue but I can't find a dictionary meaning for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a variant of [がつがつ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4) or [がっつり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8A). The person in the video uses onomatopoeia uniquely, and you should not seriously worry about its literal meaning in this case. It's used merely as a vigorous-sounding onomatopoeia and the meaning of "greedy" is not important. パラライカ is also a meaningless [地口](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44468/5010). ガッツリーナ in the latter half of the video is also in the same vein.